# How to get a specific folder in alfresco from liferay

Tags: liferay, alfresco, cmis

I'm using `Liferay 6.2` and `Alfresco community 5.0`.

I've succeeded to integrate Alfresco at Liferay with a CMIS connection.

The inheritance rule is activated on my repository(company home), and I can't  disable the inheritance on the sub folders (boss's order).

My Alfresco repository root (company home) is readable by every one, so the sub folders too.

**each users have his folder in the repository (folder's name = username)**

My boss's wish:

> when a user is authenticated in Liferay, he should only see his own
>   folder, not all the repository.

And I'm lost.

Where can I modify, or create, a `CMIS` query in order to get the user's folder, and not all the repository...

It is possible to do that or do I have write my own portlet ?

Maybe I can do that in Alfresco ?

Comment: What's the meaning of "his folder" for a client?

Comment: each user have is own folder in the repository. When a user is created a folder is created too in the repository.

Comment: Then if you can't disable permission inheritance I think the only way is to develop your own file access frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Alfresco automatically creates a user folder with private access for each user, you can find the folders in //app:company_home/app:user_homes

You should write a cmis path query that navigates to this user folder, it should look like this (example is listing files in directory for user "testuser"):

> SELECT * FROM cmis:folder WHERE
>   CONTAINS('PATH:"//app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:testuser/*"')

More in : https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/how-get-user-home-space-id-06272011-0628

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I cant use this solution.
I depend of a software developed by third party, who create automatically the user folder in the repository but don't create the alfresco user account...

Comment: What could work then is  creating an alfresco "rule" on the parentfolder of the user folders. The rule will execute when a new folder is created, you than let it execute a script where you create a new user and set adequate permissions on this newly created folder.